# Does the Hopf construction work for $S^0$?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, hopf-fibration

Given a $0$-connected $H$-space $X$, we can prove that left and right multiplication are (weak) homotopy equivalences. This allows us to construct the Hopf fibrations for $S^1$, $S^3$ and $S^7$. I always thought that $S^0$ was the odd one out due to it not being connected however after reading page 4 of "H-spaces from a homotopy point of view" I see that it is claimed $0$-connectedness can be weakened to $\pi_0(X)$ being a group.

Does this mean the real Hopf fibration can be constructed using the Hopf construction?

If so could I have some modern references?

---

This question originally stemmed from the discussion [here on the nforum](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/3391/hopf-fibration/#Item_6).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is completely elementary. From the H-space structure $X\times X\to X$ you construct the Hopf fibration $X*X\to SX$ via $(x,t,y)\to (xy,t)$, where you think of $SX$ as the quotient of $X\times I$ by identifying both the $t=1$- and $t=-1$-level to one point, respectively. For $X=S^0$ you get a fibration $S^1\to S^1$, which you „see“ is the map of degree $2$: each point has exactly two preimages. So it is actually the fibration $S^1\to RP^1$.

Comment: What are the necessary conditions for $X*X \to SX$ to be a fibration? I seem to recall X being path connected is used some essential way.

Comment: For $X=S^0$ you just see ad hoc what the map is: it is a 2-fold covering.